# Why make model -a command doesnt create resource file

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

I'm using this command for the create model,controller and resource. (laravel6)

```
php artisan make:model Patient -a
```

It creates index,create,store.. methods in controller its ok but it doesnt create any resources file in

```
app/resources/patient.php
```

Because of that I'm using one more command and then creates this file.

```
php artisan make:resource Patient
```

where is the problem? why **make:model -a** command does not create resource.php which it has toArray method.

Comment: This command `php artisan make:resource Patient` it's create resource file in this path App\Http\Resource , to use it in API response

Comment: I allready know that. read question please

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: I'm using laravel 6.

Answer (score 0):

I got a copy of Laravel 5.8 and this is what I got:

[image]

So -a option doesn't seem to include the API resource.